# Sql select query with several subqueries optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySql database with such tables:

```
PageviewEvents:
pageviewId | eventId | eventValue | eventTime

SessionPageviews:
id | sessionId | page
```

PageviewEvents.pageviewId is a refers to SessionPageviews.id as foreign key.

When I need to select some data by eventId, I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    sp.page as Page, count(*)
from PageviewEvents pe
left join SessionPageviews sp on sp.id = pe.pageviewId
where pe.eventId = 1
GROUP by sp.page
order BY 2 DESC
```

And get a table like this:

```
page | count_of_event_1
```

But now I need to select more data:

```
page | count_of_event_1 | count_of_event_2 ... | count_of_event_N
```

I started with 2 events and tried to white something like this:

```
SELECT 
    sp.page as Page, 
    (SELECT count(*) from PageviewEvents pe1 left join SessionPageviews sp1 on sp1.id = pe1.pageviewId where pe1.eventId = 1 and sp1.page = sp.page) as count_of_event_1,
    (SELECT count(*) from PageviewEvents pe1 left join SessionPageviews sp1 on sp1.id = pe1.pageviewId where pe1.eventId = 2 and sp1.page = sp.page) as count_of_event_2 
from PageviewEvents pe
left join SessionPageviews sp on sp.id = pe.pageviewId
where pe.eventId = 1 OR pe.eventId = 2
GROUP by sp.page
order BY 2 DESC
```

When I run this query on remote server, it freezes.

Are there any errors in my query? How to optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    sp.page AS Page,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pe.eventId = 1 THEN 1 END) AS count_of_event_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pe.eventId = 2 THEN 1 END) AS count_of_event_2
FROM PageviewEvents pe
LEFT JOIN SessionPageviews sp
    ON sp.id = pe.pageviewId
WHERE
    pe.eventId IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    sp.page
ORDER BY
    2 DESC;
```

Beyond the above, you may consider adding the following index to your table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON SessionPageviews (pageviewId, eventId);
```

This might help speed up the join between the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

First, your query is suspicious.  You are using a `LEFT JOIN`, but you are aggregating by a column in the *second* table.  I doubt you really want a row with a `NULL` first column.

You can write the query using conditional aggregation (as Tim) points out.  I would express this as:

```
select sp.page as Page, 
       sum( pe.eventid = 1 ) as count_of_event_1,
       sum( pe.eventid = 1 ) as count_of_event_2
from SessionPageviews sp join
     PageviewEvents pe
     on sp.id = pe.pageviewId
where pe.eventId in (1, 2)
group by sp.page
order by 2 desc;
```

Then for this query, there are two indexing strategies.  If you have many types of events (or if 1 and 2 are relatively rare), then:

- `SessionPageviews(id, page)`
- `PageviewEvents(eventId, pageviewId)`

Otherwise:

- `SessionPageviews(page, id)`
- `PageviewEvents(pageviewId, eventId)`